# htacess 301 redirect with query string from page that does not exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My old search file used to be named namesearch.php.  It's now named search.php.  The query string parameters remain the same.  I would like to redirect any namesearch request to search.php.  Here is what I have below, which is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^/namesearch.php%1 search.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query strings are automatically appended when the target URI doesn't try to construct its own (i.e. it doesn't have a `?` in it). You can use either mod_rewrite or mod_alias:

mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /namesearch.php /search.php
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?namesearch.php /search.php [L,R=301]
```